# Stop the (pojo) serialization if one of the required fields is null

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Consider the following POJO:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

@JsonInclude(content=Include.NON_NULL)
public class User {
    @JsonProperty(required=true)
    private String username;
    private String dob;
    private String email;
    //        ... (getters and setters)

}
```

consider the following sample JSON for the above pojo:

```
{
    "username": "foo",
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    "dob": "12/21/1994"
}
```

and if I assign a field as `null` it'll be ignored while the serialization takes place.

coming to my question, is there a way to stop the serialization(throw an exception) when a required field is `null`, because currently **Jackson** considers `null` as a value hence, this does not violate the contract specified by `@JsonProperty(required=true)`

I need the `username` field to be always present in my json.

I have tried using `@NotNull` with `javax.validation:validation-api`, that didn't seem to work.

It's a **spring-boot 1.5.2** application.

**P.S.**
Please feel free to suggest other usable APIs or to edit the question to make it better.

Answer (score -1):

you can use something link this will help you out.

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

or:

```
  @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    class User
    {
    private String username;
    private String dob;
    private String email;
    ......
    .......
    }
```

Comment: The serialization would take place.
I want the serialization to stop if the username is null.